# How can I change the header of the DataGridViewColumn in Windows Forms?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I checked on other postings and suggested to make the `EnableHeadersVisualStyles = false` but that only lets me color them. I want to change their names, but they don't change when I force the name as shown below.

```
Products prod = new Products();
DataTable dt = prod.GetTopTenTransactions(Global.Instance.Accounts[0]);
transactionGrid.DataSource = dt;

foreach (DataGridViewColumn cols in transactionGrid.Columns)
{
    cols.Width = 70;
}

transactionGrid.ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.CadetBlue;
transactionGrid.EnableHeadersVisualStyles = false; 

transactionGrid.Columns[0].Name = "ID";
transactionGrid.Columns[1].Name = "TYPE";
transactionGrid.Columns[2].Name = "DATE";
transactionGrid.Columns[3].Name = "AMOUNT";
transactionGrid.Columns[4].Name = "FROM";
transactionGrid.Columns[5].Name = "TO";
transactionGrid.Columns[6].Name = "TELLER ID";
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[DataGridViewColumn.Name](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcolumn.name.aspx) is used to identify column in collection.
Try to use [DataGridViewColumn.HeaderText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcolumn.headertext.aspx) instead.

Answer (score 5):

You should use [`HeaderText`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcolumn.headertext.aspx) property:

```
transactionGrid.Columns[0].HeaderText = "Header";
```

Answer (score 0):

1. If you are using a predefined set of columns (known at design time), then
   in visual studio select the datagrid, go to properties
   in columns click the <kbd>...</kbd> button
   this opens up an extra window, in which you can edit the details of your column
2. If you are doing things at runtime, then in the code behind file use:

   `datagrid.Columns[index].HeaderText = "new value";`

Hope this helps.